# econf fails when installing pth

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I'm just starting out with Gentoo and I'm getting a bit stuck installing programs with Portage. It's wonderful and automatic except when it isn't.

Many of the programs I try to install (git, gedit, chrome, nautilus) eventually depend on pth, whatever that is. But it fails with an econf error:

```
   ERROR: dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo failed (configure phase):
     econf failed

   Call stack:
            ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called src_configure
          environment, line 2881:  Called econf '--disable-static'
     phase-helpers.sh, line  577:  Called die
   The specific snippet of code:
                die "econf failed"

   If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo'`,
   the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo'`.
   The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/temp/build.log'.
   The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/temp/environment'.
   Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work/pth-2.0.7'
```

Here is the ebuild line

```
[ebuild  N    ] dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3  USE="-debug -static-libs"
```

and the [emerge info](http://pastebin.com/ewLhtTSH) I put on pastebin because of its length.

Buildlog:

```
 * Package:    dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3
 * Repository: gentoo
 * Maintainer: crypto@gentoo.org
 * USE:        abi_x86_64 amd64 elibc_glibc kernel_linux multilib userland_GNU
 * FEATURES:   preserve-libs sandbox userpriv usersandbox
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking pth-2.0.7.tar.gz to /var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work/pth-2.0.7 ...
 * Applying pth-2.0.5-parallelfix.patch ...                              [ ok ]
 * Applying pth-2.0.6-ldflags.patch ...                                  [ ok ]
 * Applying pth-2.0.6-sigstack.patch ...                                 [ ok ]
 * Applying pth-2.0.7-parallel-install.patch ...                         [ ok ]
 * Applying pth-2.0.7-ia64.patch ...                                     [ ok ]
 * Applying pth-2.0.7-kernel-3.patch ...                                 [ ok ]
 * Replacing obsolete head/tail with POSIX compliant ones
 *  - fixed aclocal.m4
 *  - fixed configure
 * Running elibtoolize in: pth-2.0.7/
 *   Applying portage/1.5.10 patch ...
 *   Applying max_cmd_len/1.5.20 patch ...
 *   Applying sed/1.5.6 patch ...
 *   Applying as-needed/1.5 patch ...
 *   Applying target-nm/2.4.2 patch ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work/pth-2.0.7 ...
 * econf: updating pth-2.0.7/config.sub with /usr/share/gnuconfig/config.sub
 * econf: updating pth-2.0.7/config.guess with /usr/share/gnuconfig/config.guess
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --libdir=/usr/lib64 --disable-static
./configure: line 286: /tmp/autoconf.25970: Permission denied
./configure: line 297: /tmp/autoconf.25970: Permission denied
./configure: line 310: /tmp/autoconf.25970: No such file or directory
 * ERROR: dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo failed (configure phase):
 *   econf failed
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *          ebuild.sh, line   93:  Called src_configure
 *        environment, line 2887:  Called econf '--disable-static'
 *   phase-helpers.sh, line  577:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *              die "econf failed"
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work/pth-2.0.7'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/work/pth-2.0.7'
```

What is going wrong here, and how do  fix it?

Comment: Look for a file called "config.log" somewhere under `/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/` - that should have the actual error.

Comment: @Mat: No such file. The only .log files anywhere under that directory are `build`, `eclass-debug`, `epatch`, and `elibtool`.

Comment: Unfortunately, non of the provided logs shows the actual error. A @Mat already pointed out, there should be another log somewhere in `/var/tmp/portage/dev-libs/pth-2.0.7-r3/` that contains the error. Hint: Try installing `wgetpaste` and once you located the missing log, that has to exists, you can use this tool to paste the log.

Comment: @Flow: I managed to get the buildlog which I edited into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `/tmp` was not writable except by root, for some reason. I fixed the problem with

```
chmod a+w /tmp
```

I have no idea how this came to be; it's a fresh install and I certainly didn't intentionally change the permissions to `drwxr-xr-`.

Comment: Proper permissions for `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are `rwxrwxrwt` (or 1777).